# Ink tutorial: substrate-contracts-node does not produce blocks

Tags: ink, substrate-contracts-node

I am following the Ink tutorial at https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/ink-workshop/pt1/ .

When running `substrate-contracts-node --dev` no block is produced.

Only log line produced is:

```
2022-04-22 11:26:45  Operating system: macos    
2022-04-22 11:26:45  CPU architecture: aarch64    
2022-04-22 11:26:45  Highest known block at #0    
2022-04-22 11:26:45 〽️ Prometheus exporter started at 127.0.0.1:9615    
2022-04-22 11:26:45 Listening for new connections on 127.0.0.1:9944.    
2022-04-22 11:26:46 Accepted a new tcp connection from 127.0.0.1:59063.    
2022-04-22 11:26:50  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0x02ba…032a), finalized #0 (0x02ba…032a), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0    
2022-04-22 11:26:55  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0x02ba…032a), finalized #0 (0x02ba…032a), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0    
2022-04-22 11:27:00  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0x02ba…032a), finalized #0 (0x02ba…032a), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0    
2022-04-22 11:27:05  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0x02ba…032a), finalized #0 (0x02ba…032a), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0    
2022-04-22 11:27:10  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0x02ba…032a), finalized #0 (0x02ba…032a), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0    

[.....]
```

am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Substrate contracts node uses instant block seals. You need to send transactions to produce blocks.

> The instant seal consensus engine, and its cousin the manual seal consensus engine, are both included in the same [sc-consensus-manual-seal](https://docs.rs/sc-consensus-manual-seal/latest/sc_consensus_manual_seal/) crate. Instant seal simply authors a new block whenever a new transaction is available in the queue.

Comment: thank you @burak - my problem is that https://paritytech.github.io/contracts-ui/ shows connection error and cannot connect to local node, preventing contract deployment

Comment: I had to add `--unsafe-ws-external` to `substrate-contracts-node` but not sure this is correct

Comment: You can add `--dev` and it should connect